# A Past Numeric Date without Time

Tags: javascript, date, time, numeric

I've been searching and I can't find a solution for this.

I need javascript code that displays the date in the `mm/dd/yyyy` without displaying the time, but I need it to be a past date. Like for instance 61 days prior to today's date. Whatever the date is, it will display the date 61 days ago.

Comment: And, what have you tried? http://whathaveyoutried.com

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [moment library](http://momentjs.com/)

And do:

```
moment().subtract('days', 61).calendar()
```

Answer (score 0):

Would this work for you: `var PastDate = new Date(pastyear, pastmonth, pastday);`

Check here for more details: [Date-Javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

Then if you wanted to get a string with just the Date and no time use something like this:

```
 var stringDate = ++PastDate.GetMonth() + "/" + PastDate.GetDate() +"/" + PastDate.GetFullYear();
```